# Exporting a variable to Excel in R

Tags: r, writexl

I created a correlation of several variables in R.

```r
df <- read_excel("~/R/Track/Cumulative_2023.xlsx")
Rel <- cor(df[, c('Speed', 'Axis', 'Horz', 'Ext', 'Zone', 'Rel')], use="complete.obs")
```

I am using the code:

```r
W <- write.xlsx(Rel, file = "~/R/Track/correlation.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1", colNames = TRUE, rowNames = TRUE)
```

When I run W I get a spreadsheet that has the number 1 in the 1st row/column.  I can't figure it out. If I write.xls using the df variable instead of Rel, it writes it properly.

I should be able to export the Rel variable with no issues right?

I was expecting to export the Rel variable to Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Inferring `openxlsx::write.xlsx`, it is getting confused by the the class of `Rel`. Wrap it in `as.data.frame(.)` and you'll get what you want.

Reprex:

```r
cor(mtcars[,1:3])
#             mpg        cyl       disp
# mpg   1.0000000 -0.8521620 -0.8475514
# cyl  -0.8521620  1.0000000  0.9020329
# disp -0.8475514  0.9020329  1.0000000
openxlsx::write.xlsx(cor(mtcars[,1:3]), "mt.xlsx", colNames=TRUE, rowNames=TRUE)
```

[image: incorrect object]

The fix:

```r
openxlsx::write.xlsx(as.data.frame(cor(mtcars[,1:3])), "mt.xlsx", colNames=TRUE, rowNames=TRUE)
```

[image: excel file, fixed]

Comment: I could not get this to work. FYI, the class of Rel is "matrix" "array". When I run a variable that is filtered off the original df it works.  Something like this- A <- df %>% filter(Name == "Matt")) will write properly to excel. But as soon as I run that "Rel" variable with the correlations, it just returns a 1 in the 1st column/row.

Comment: FYI, the class of `class(cor(mtcars[,1:3]))` is _also_ `c("matrix", "array")`. I don't see how `df %>% filter(..)` can work on a matrix, it should fail. Otherwise, there's nothing I can do: the reprex I provided is complete, reproduces your symptom, and is fixed by converting to a frame. We don't have your `"Cumulative_2023.xlsx"`, perhaps you can add the output from `dput(Rel)` into your question and we can see what else is different about your data.

Comment: This solved it.... so simple. df1 <- as.data.frame(df). Worked once I converted the Matrix to a Data Frame. Thank you all for the help.